# How to get alert for LDAP issues

Tags: ssh, ldap

I want to run some script which checks for LDAP issue, and in case the LDAP server is down (checking against port), it will send me an alert. I thought using ssh command with some genric user, but I'm not sure what is the response I'm expecting to get in case LDAP server is down. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends with your requirement. If you just need to verify whether the LDAP server is up and running with a script, you can simply check one or more of below,

1. Check the LDAP port (usually 389) is up
2. Can connect successfully
3. Can run a simple query

I think this is sufficient for an automated routine check.

For example, assuming you have setup netcat and ldap-utils, in a bash script you can use the below commands to assess whether the service is up.

```sh
    nc -zv <LDAP Server IP address>
    ldapsearch -x -h <LDAP Server IP address> -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w <password to connect>
```

The downside of this method is you always need to send the password in clear text. Further, I would suggest to write a small piece of code in python or golang to do the same.

Comment: How can I check it was connected successfully? and which query I can run?

Comment: Several ways, 

1. Can netcat to the LDAP server:port

nc <Server IP address> <LDAP port> </dev/null 

You have to install nc on the client or scanning machine.

2. Use ldapsearch command to make sure the LDAP server is up, can log in with the credentials and also can do a basic search

ldapsearch -D <usernam> -w <password> -x -b "uid=username,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com"

Comment: @arielma, in order to make the things clear, I have updated the comment. Please have a look!

Comment: I will make it more simple for now. I want to sent alert for the below case: `ping: ldap.corp.XXXXX.com: Name or service not known`. how can I catch this response?
`

Comment: @arielma looks like a DNS issue. Can you make sure the IP address is reachable instead? or run ```nslookup ldap.corp.XXXXX.com```